Part number of this IC marking "302 0"
I want to know the part numbers of this IC.
Thanks,


[![enter image description here][2]][2]

As I measured in PCB, If this IC marking 302 below is a P Mosfet channel, this schematic will be the picture. I'm not sure if this part number is correct or not.
In this picture, Vout is output from AD5390BCPZ-5 (IC DAC), and I think the schematic is a buffer for Vout.
So can anyone help me, please?

It's probably an Onsemi FDN302P p-channel MOSFET.


(Source: lcsc.com)

Does anyone have ideas for other part numbers?

pretty sure that is the one, your marking is typical of Fairchild/Onsemi products. example: https://in.rsdelivers.com/product/onsemi/fdn86246/n-channel-mosfet-16-a-150-v-3-pin-sot-23-onsemi/1662695
